# Coq how to pretty-print a term constructed using tactics?

Tags: coq

I'm new to Coq and am doing some exercises to get more familiar with it.

My understanding is that proving a proposition in Coq "really" is writing down a type in Gallina and then showing that it's inhabited using tactics to combine terms together in deterministic ways.

I'm wondering if there's a way to get a pretty-printed representation of the actual term, with all the tactics removed.

In the example below, an anonymous term of type `plus_comm (x y : N) : plus x y = plus y x` is ultimately produced... I think. What should I do if I want to look at it? In a certain sense, I'm curious what the tactics "desugar" to.

Here's the code in question, lifted essentially verbatim from a tutorial on YouTube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OaIn7g8BAIc.

```
Inductive N : Type :=
| O : N
| S : N -> N
.

Fixpoint plus (x y : N) : N :=
match x with
| O => y
| S x' => S (plus x' y)
end.

Lemma plus_0 (x : N) : plus x O = x.

Proof.
  induction x.
  - simpl. reflexivity.
  - simpl. rewrite IHx. reflexivity.
Qed.

Lemma plus_S (x y : N) : plus x (S y) = S(plus x y).

Proof.
  induction x.
  - simpl. reflexivity.
  - simpl. rewrite IHx. reflexivity.
Qed.


Lemma plus_comm (x y : N) : plus x y = plus y x.

Proof.
  induction x.
  - simpl. rewrite plus_0. reflexivity.
  - simpl. rewrite IHx. rewrite plus_S. reflexivity.
Qed.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `plus_comm` is *not* a part of the type. You get a term *named* `plus_comm` of type `forall x y : N,  plus x y = plus y x.` You can check it using the following command

```
Check plus_comm.
```

So, an alternative way of defining the `plus_comm` lemma is

```
Lemma plus_comm : forall x y : N, plus x y = plus y x.
```

As a side note: in this case you'll need to add `intros x y.` (or just `intros.`) after the `Proof.` part.

Tactics (and the means to glue them together) are a metalanguage called Ltac, because they are used to produce terms of another language, called Gallina, which is the specification language of Coq.

For example, `forall x y : N, plus x y = plus y x` is an instance of Gallina sentence as well as the body of the `plus` function. To obtain the term attached to `plus_comm` use the `Print` command:

```
Print plus_comm.

plus_comm = 
fun x y : N =>
N_ind (fun x0 : N => plus x0 y = plus y x0)
  (eq_ind_r (fun n : N => y = n) eq_refl (plus_0 y))
  (fun (x0 : N) (IHx : plus x0 y = plus y x0) =>
   eq_ind_r (fun n : N => S n = plus y (S x0))
     (eq_ind_r (fun n : N => S (plus y x0) = n) eq_refl (plus_S y x0))
     IHx) x
     : forall x y : N, plus x y = plus y x
```

It is not an easy read, but with some experience you'll be able to understand it.

Incidentally, here is how we could have proved the lemma not using tactics:

```
Definition plus_comm : forall x y : N, plus x y = plus y x :=
  fix IH (x y : N) :=
    match x return plus x y = plus y x with
    | O => eq_sym (plus_0 y)
    | S x => eq_ind _ (fun p => S p = plus y (S x)) (eq_sym (plus_S y x)) _ (eq_sym (IH x y))
    end.
```

To explain a few things: `fix` is the means of defining recursive functions, `eq_sym` is used to change `x = y` into `y = x`, and `eq_ind` corresponds to the `rewrite` tactic.